# What is the number that appears when I use Doomfist's Seismic Slam?

Tags: overwatch

When I use Seismic Slam (E on PC), a number appears under the targeting reticle. It seems to vary between ~35 and ~90 depending on how far I travel. Does damage vary by distance traveled? I couldn't find anything on [Doomfists' hero details](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/doomfist/) to indicate what the number refers to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the amount of damage dealt by Seismic Slam. It increases the longer Doomfist is in the air while using it, up to a maximum of 125.

Comment: Illustrative picture of how the damage scales: http://imgur.com/dX7m8Jl

Comment: @TimmyJim I have no idea what that image is trying to explain